# Print only the final value of incremented integer in Python

Tags: python, printing, integer, pcap, ordereddictionary

I have this code in Python where I increment an integer every time I find a specific packet. I want to print in the end the final value of the integer, but python prints me all the values that the integer takes during the incrementation. I have tried the same thing with orderedDict, but it's the same thing, it prints all the values, but I want only the last one. How can i print only the final value in both cases?

This is some part of the code:
[image]

And this is the result. I want to print only the 1890 value.
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change the "foreach" loop into a regular "for in range" loop and only print when it reaches the last iteration.

Comment: I can't do this because PCAPS are packets from a pcap file.

Comment: Then you can make an list, replace the print statement with adding the ip_count to the list, then after it's all done, print the last element of the list. It's a bit inefficient but it does the job.

Comment: Actually, ignore what I just said, just make a variable, and replace the print statement with updating the variable, so by the time the loop ends, the variable will hold the value of the last ip_count

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand your last comment

Comment: initialize a variable before the for loop, say ```temp_ip_count```. replace ```print(ip_count)``` with ```temp_ip_count = ip_count```. Then after the for loop ends, write ```print(temp_ip_count)```.